# VUE + NODE = как

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Всем привет.

Объясните как правильно ...

Хочу писать фронтенд на VUE как правильно взаимодействовать с node.js

1. Вариант: node сам по себе vue сам, из vue через axios решаю все вопросы
2. Вариант: node + vue соединить, как тут, но я попробовал, выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: ОШИБКА]

Comment: Я читал официальную доку и рендер на сервере тоже, не получается

Comment: vue cli сам подтягивает ноду. Для серверного рендеринга используйте vue + nuxt js, он совсем не сложный и во многом облегчает жизнь.

Comment: А почему про него пишут, что не универсальный, не гибкий? Можете развеять?  Вот тут https://habr.com/ru/post/458396/

Comment: Ну, пока что, особо не возникали проблемы. Были как-то траблы с автороутами. Пришлось хардкодить и переделывать на свои роуты, но там задача была довольно нетривиальная, поэтому гемморой был бы и без него, все равно. В целом, возможно, он в каких-то супер не стандартных задачах может быть не совсем гибким, но а как по-другому?, вы платите этим за автоматизацию разработки и кучу сэкономленного времени, это нормально. На мой взгляд, это маст хэв инструмент  для vuejs разработчика.